# What is the API to get the detail information of a directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am a new to Objective-c, I want to get the detail infomation for the local directory (like name, size, last modify time). Is there any API that could help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope you will find your answer here:

- [Getting the Attributes of a File or Directory](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_in_Objective-C)

> The attributes of a file or directory can be obtained using the
>   **attributesOfItemAtPath** method. This takes as arguments the path of the
>   directory and an optional NSError object into which information about
>   any errors will be placed (may be specified as NULL if this
>   information is not required). The results are returned in the form of
>   an NSDictionary dictionary object (for details of working with
>   dictionary objects refer to Objective-C Dictionary Objects).

Some keys for this dictionary:

```
NSFileType
NSFileTypeDirectory
NSFileTypeBlockSpecial
NSFileTypeUnknown
NSFileSize
NSFileModificationDate
NSFileOwnerAccountName
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName
NSFilePosixPermissions
NSFileSystemNumber
NSFileCreationDate
NSFileOwnerAccountID
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID
```

**Example from above article:**

*(we can extract the creation date, file type and POSIX permissions for the /tmp directory using the following code excerpt)*

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSDictionary *attribs;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

attribs = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath: @"/tmp" error: NULL];

NSLog (@"Created on %@", [attribs objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate]);
NSLog (@"File type %@", [attribs objectForKey: NSFileType]);
NSLog (@"POSIX Permissions %@", [attribs objectForKey: NSFilePosixPermissions]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The bleeding edge (may.13.2012) is using CFURL/NSURL properties:

```
id outName = nil;
NSString * key = NSURLNameKey;
NSError * outError = nil;

if (YES == [url getResourceValue:&value forKey:key error:&outError]) {
  NSString * name = outName;
  ...
}
```

Note: Make sure you request only what you need, and note that there are batch request methods/functions to minimize redundant requests. If using NSURL, you can use:

```
NSArray * keys = ...;
NSError * outError = nil;
NSDictionary * properties = [url resourceValuesForKeys:keys error:&outError];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API. In particular the `-attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` method.